# Congratulations to Brian M. Scott!! (200K edition)

Tags: discussion, reputation, specific-user, celebration

It's been a little more than two weeks since [our last celebration](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/11183/8348), but today another math.SE user has passed the 200K barrier!

Prof. Scott's habit of providing [fantastic answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/12042/brian-m-scott?tab=answers) to questions of all sorts is, in my opinion, remarkable.  But this is surpassed by his patience in providing further explanations as users need them.  His dedication to math.SE is truly something to behold!

## A hearty and well-earned congratulations!!

---

*(On a personal note, Brian has inspired many of my own personal answering habits on the main site, though I obviously have not caught on to his prolificity.  As my mathematical interests are pretty much a proper subset of his, anytime an answer of mine is accepted over one of his I take it as a small — and exceedingly rare — badge of honour.  While I don't really ask questions on the main site, I have learned a lot from Brian, mathematically and otherwise.  Thanks!)*

Comment: Congrats @BrianMScott!  Thank you for dedicating time and effort into making Math.SE a great site!

Comment: Definitely a user to keep hold of.

Comment: thanks sir for help us tremendously

Comment: @Brian you rock! :) thanks for helping us!

Comment: @Thanks a lot Brian! Your answers are very student-friendly! Congrats!

Comment: Congratulations Brian! So when are you writing a book on general topology? :) And also, thanks for making us [feel better.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478422/prove-that-if-33-rooks-are-placed-on-a-chessboard-at-least-five-dont-attack-on/478440?noredirect=1#comment1030489_478440) :)

Comment: The "I beat Brian's answer once" badge is a good idea! and congratulations professor @BrianM.Scott .

Comment: Thank you all very much. @Prism: I wrote perhaps two-thirds of an undergraduate-level topology text back in the $1970$s but stopped when I realized that it was going to end up too long to be publishable. I still have the manuscript, and I’ve occasionally thought about retyping it in electronic form, perhaps with revisions, making it available on-line, and perhaps even completing it. But it would be a real chore, and I keep putting it off in favor of other things — like answering questions here or helping people with [Old Norse questions](http://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/norse_course/info).

Comment: @Brian: If you think it would help you finish your text, I could suspend you for a year or so....$\;$;-)$\;\;$(Can't do anything about the Old Norse, however.)

Comment: @Brian Congrats! Your answers tend to be canonical in away that transcends the usual time horizon of internet life.

Comment: 2 Downvotes!!!!

Comment: What happenned to sir @BrianMScott ? His last seen is stuck at 1 year back 

Answer (score 25):

Thanks to Brian and André, I aced my discrete mathematics exam in college :)

A big thanks for all your patience and awesomeness! You make math less painful!

Comment: Congratulations on the exam!

Answer (score 16):

Simply Pleased and Extremely Delighted, It is my great pleasure to congratulate Prof. Scott.  $+\infty$ amount of Thank you Sir!

Answer (score 14):

Congrats Prof. Scott. Just looked at one of your answers that is helping me for my homework and saw "203k", had to congratulate. Keep posting your detailed insight to us mortals!

Answer (score 12):

If it's ok I'd like to add my thanks to Prof. Scott here.  He's helped me in like a dozen or so questions, some I was not too far off and some I just didn't understand the 1st thing about what I was doing.  Either way, after his comments and corrections I quickly understood how the concept worked and why.  I feel like I've learned more from him than from some of my professors that I see in person.